# Why do I on git get ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host?

Tags: git, github, ssh

Cloning a repo form the terminal:

```
git clone git@github.foohost.com:barrepo.git
Cloning into 'foorepo'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've followed the steps on [generating and adding the SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) but when 
[I test my SSH connection](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection) I have the same result:

```
ssh -T git@github.foohost.com:
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

using verbose

```
ssh -v git@github.foohost.com
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Fred/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/Fred/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/Fred/.ssh/config line 27: Applying options for github.foohost.com
debug1: /Users/Fred/.ssh/config line 41: Applying options for *.foohost.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q b.snc1 nc github 22
debug1: identity file /Users/Fred/.ssh/baz_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/Fred/.ssh/baz_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I can clone the repo using https but after that I cannot perform other actions (checkout/push...).

Any suggestions what may cause this or how to fix it?

Comment: You may try the steps from [this](http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification) website, like `ssh -v` for more verbose output. P.S. You may update your question with the verbose output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Did just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this was due to a missing VPN connection.

Also, @YesThatIsMyName commented:

> You may try the steps from [this](http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification) website, like ssh -v for more verbose
> output. P.S. You may update your question with the verbose output. –